# my php command lost when session_start and destry

Tags: c#, php, html, ubuntu, websocket

my webserver consist of C# server program, html and php

is running well

but when i send reset configurations command to C# program and logout to pages

then that commands is lost

this is my code

**Server <-> JS <-> Html**

C# Server Program(Received Part,Websocket Server)

using WebSocketSharp;

using WebSocketSharp.Server;

C# Program.cs

```
static WebSocketServer webSocketServer;

public static class Program
{
  webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(7777);
  webSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<Chat>("/Chat");
  webSocketServer.Start();
}

public static void CommandConverter(Model_CMD model_CMD)
{
   switch(MdeolCMD.cmd)
   {
      case "Config":
        switch (model_CMD.Parameter)
        {
           case "RESET":
           ConfingRESET();
           break;
        }
        break;
   }
}
```

C# Chat.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class Chat : WebSocketBehavior
{
 protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
 {
   var text = e.Data;
   Model_CMD model_CMD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model_CMD>(text);
   Program.CommandConverter(model_CMD, ID, true);        
 }
}
```

C# Model_CMD.cs

```
public class Model_CMD
{
  public Model_CMD(string CMD, string Parameter, string Value = "", string Value2 = "", string Return = "")
  {
     this.CMD = CMD;
     this.Parameter = Parameter;
     this.Value = Value;
     this.Value2 = Value2;
     this.Return = Return;
  }


   public string CMD { get; set; }
   public string Parameter { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public string Value2 { get; set; }
   public string Return { get; set; }
}
```

JS Part(Send Command)

```
function Configuration_Reset()
{
  var s_data = {};
  s_data["id"] = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>";
  s_data["pw"] = "<?=$_SESSION['user_pw']?>";
        
        SendCMD("RESET","Config",s_data["id"].toString(),s_data["pw"].toString());
        window.location.href = "./logout.php";
    
}

function SendCMD(CMD,  Parameter,  Value1,  Value2)
{
  var s_data = {};
  s_data["CMD"] = CMD;
  s_data["Parameter"] = Parameter;
  s_data["Value"] = Value1;
  s_data["Value2"] = Value2;
  s_data["Return"] = "";

  socket.send((JSON.stringify(s_data));
}
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=login.php'>
```

can i have some try?

-- ADDED

html js Command to C# Program

then transmitted well in C# when without logout.php after command
(if in js part without `window.location.href = "./logout.php";`
then C# server can catch command)

but send command and call logout.php then anything catch on C# Program

so how i can catch command in c# when command send and logout

-- ADDED

C# Minimal code add to run C# server

Comment: The code in _"PHP Part(Send Command)"_ is JavaScript¸ not PHP.

Comment: `PHP Part`...nope, that's JavaScript (with a tiny bit of PHP embedded in it).

Comment: Anyway you're going to have to provide more context and clarity. We don't know what "lost" means. We don't know what behaviour you were expecting, and specifically what behaviour occurred instead. We don't know what the socket server actually does when you send the "RESET" command. If it sets a Session value, then yes obviously that will be lost when you log out, because you're (correctly, for security reasons) destroying the session. We can't fix anything because we don't fully understand the problem or the requirements. See [ask] and then [edit] the question when you have more information.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, i edit php -> js and some explanation added

Comment: We still don't know what the websocket server does or how it would relate to your PHP session. We need a [mre] of the issue. Currently we do not have sufficient information to understand the issue.

Comment: @ADyson thank you adyson ,, i not good at english.. and this site 
thanks for letting me know and i add code about C# server code